# How to notify user flash is not installed (without javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, flash, detection

I would like to notify with a very simple text (Flash is not installed on your browser)

But i don't want to use Javascript or swfobject and etc...

I just want to use simple HTML codes

Can i do something like this code:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<object ...codes...>
<param ...codes...>
<param ...codes...>
<embed  ...codes...>
</embed>
Flash is not installed on your pc!
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can not.

HTML is what it says, it's a markup language. You need to use js.

Comment: can you make an example with a very simple javascript? output: (Flash is not installed on your browser) tnx

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/130r9fka/ (set it to echo your output if hasFlash is false)

Comment: @MahdiJazini Only the notification?

Comment: @TristandeJager yes just a simple short text. because i need for old mobile browsers

Comment: @MahdiJazini: modify the jsfiddle provided with an alert function to pop up a notification with text of your choosing

Comment: @ManmeetGill where should i put the object html tag and the alert function? tnx :'(

Comment: @mahdijazini, I'm on mobile so can't help too much, but you can use "alert("you have no flash!");" If hasFlash is false. I'll try an expand tomorrow if need be.

Comment: @ManmeetGill So i should put the flash objects between the div tag yes?

Comment: You can put it anywhere, the js simply checks if the user has flash

Comment: @ManmeetGill thank you very much for the sample code... also i have sent a post under your post to complete your answer... but marked your answer as the best answer :) tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have made a simple code based on [@Manmeet Gill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5284221/manmeet-gill) Comment:

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="chart"></div>

<Script Language="JavaScript">
 var hasFlash = false;
 try {
  hasFlash = Boolean(new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash'));
 } catch(exception) {
  hasFlash = ('undefined' != typeof navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash']);
 }
 
if (hasFlash==true) {
    document.getElementById('chart').innerHTML = "<!-- Flash HTML Code here -->"
} else {
        document.getElementById('chart').innerHTML = "<b>Flash Player Not Installed</b>"
}

</Script>
</body>
</html>
```

The **Script** tag should be after the **div** tag and both should be in the **body** tag